# Has Neo ever told anyone the *detailed* truth?

Tags: the-matrix

At the end of Reloaded, Neo finds some revelations.

[image: How]

He summarizes them to the team and assures them he is sure it is the *truth*.

Did Neo ever go into any detail about the truth he found? Beyond the information he told the crew here? Namely,

## ! massive spoiler alert !

> MORPHEUS: ... the war should be over.  
>  NEO: In twenty four hours, it will be. [...] If we don't do something in the next twenty four hours, Zion will be destroyed.  
>  TRINITY: How do you know that?  
>  NEO: I was told it would happen-,  
>  MORPHEUS: By who?  
>  NEO: It doesn't matter. I believed him.  
>  MORPHEUS: It's impossible. The prophecy tells us–  
>  NEO: It was a lie, Morpheus. The prophecy was a lie. The One was never meant to end anything. It was all another system of control.  I'm sorry. I know it isn't easy to hear but I swear to you, it's the truth.

This is not quite as much informative as it originally was. Is he the only *one* around in the human world who knows the full version?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is constructive. In the films (including the Animatrix) we are not shown that he reveals additional information. So, we can only speculate if he told Trinity off-screen while travelling to the machine city.

Comment: @bitmask why would he choose not to tell the information anyone? For example when they travel with car to the Oracle, he could have the time to explain it. This information would seemingly be useful to make Roland let him his ship, for example.

Comment: @bitmask In that case, I don't think this would be "not constructive", that could be an answer - something along the lines of "nothing was shown in A, B, C...."

Comment: @Izkata, @ naxa: It would be a rather boring answer to repeat the question and say "no, I don't remember it being said on-screen" (which would really be the only relevant statement to answer the question). The alternative is to engage in idle speculation. So, perhaps you can edit the question to shift its scope. There's a good question hidden there, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: @bitmask well it would be interesting to include the Matrix Online, the Comics, websites, website secret areas (remember?). Maybe hidden levels on video games, hidden video games areas that lead to hidden websites, etc... :) They were written/overseen by the writers+directors.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I've been able to tell, the full truth of the matter dies with him.  It's never shown that he told Morpheus about it, on- or off-screen.  It's never indicated that he told Trinity either.  While it's possible to believe he told someone off-screen, we have no evidence for that.  Furthermore, this would help put some strength into the slightly philosophical comment of "it doesn't matter--I believed him."  Therefore, I think it's safe to assume he never told anyone.

I always thought it was odd that he never told anyone the specifics about the Architect.  You'd think that would be important information.